# Setting up PactJS with Angular and GraphQL

Tags: angular, graphql, apollo, pact

I'm trying to set up PactJS with Angular and GraphQL.

In my project I send request to /api endpoint. I'm redirecting it to another host using our backend like a proxy.

When I run `npm run test` I see this exception

[image: When I run <code>npm run test</code> I see this exception]

My Service, which I need to test as a consumer

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Apollo } from 'apollo-angular';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';


@Injectable()
export class DataService {
    static itemQueries = require('graphql-tag/loader!./queries.graphql');

    constructor(private apollo: Apollo) {}

    getData(path: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.apollo
            .query<{ item }>({
                query: DataService.itemQueries['GetData'],
                fetchPolicy: 'no-cache',
                variables: {
                    path,
                },
            })
            .pipe(
                map((result) => {
                    return result;
                })
            );
    }
}
```

pact.spec.ts
Actually, here I'm testing `expect('Home').toBe('Home');` but it's just to be sure everything is configured in a right way.

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { PactWeb } from '@pact-foundation/pact-web';
import { ApolloModule, APOLLO_OPTIONS } from 'apollo-angular';
import { HttpLink, HttpLinkModule } from 'apollo-angular-link-http';
import { ApolloTestingController } from 'apollo-angular/testing';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';
import { DataService } from './data.service';

function createApollo(httpLink: HttpLink) {
    return {
        link: httpLink.create({ uri: 'http://localhost:1234/api' }),
        cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    };
}

describe('DataService to CMS Data Contract', function() {
    let service: DataService;
    let provider;

    const EXPECTED_BODY = {
        result: true
    };

    beforeAll((done) => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [ApolloModule, HttpLinkModule, HttpClientModule],
            providers: [
                DataService,
                {
                    provide: APOLLO_OPTIONS,
                    useFactory: createApollo,
                    deps: [HttpLink],
                },
            ],
        });

        service = TestBed.get(DataService);

        provider = new PactWeb({
            consumer: '',
            provider: '',
            spec: 2,
        });

        provider.removeInteractions().then(done, done.fail);
    });

    afterEach(async (done) => {
        provider.verify().then(done, done.fail);
    });

    afterAll(async (done) => {
        provider.finalize().then(done, done.fail);
    });

    describe('and there is a valid user session', () => {
        beforeEach(async (done) => {
            provider
                .addInteraction({
                    state: 'i have a list of projects',
                    uponReceiving: 'a request for projects',
                    withRequest: {
                        method: 'POST',
                        path: '/api',
                        headers: {
                            Accept: 'application/json',
                        },
                    },
                    willRespondWith: {
                        status: 200,
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                        },
                        body: EXPECTED_BODY,
                    },
                })
                .then(done, done.fail);
        });

        it('generates a Content root item', async (done) => {
            console.log('start test');
            service.getData('path').subscribe((item) => {
                expect('Home').toBe('Home');
                done();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

karma.conf.js

[image]

Reference to test file and project you can find on github
https://github.com/stativa/pact

**UPDATE:**

Now I'm getting

```
Failed: Actual interactions do not match expected interactions for mock MockService.

Missing requests:
    OPTIONS http://localhost:1234/api
```

However, I have

```
provider
                .addInteraction({
                    state: 'i have a list of projects',
                    uponReceiving: 'a request for projects',
                    withRequest: {
                        method: 'OPTIONS',
                        path: 'http://localhost:1234/api',
                    },
                    willRespondWith: {
                        status: 200,
                        body: { },
                    },
                })
                .then(done, done.fail);
```

Comment: were you  aable to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be CORS related. Have you read the wiki page on CORS? https://github.com/pact-foundation/pact-mock_service/wiki/Using-the-mock-service-with-CORS

Comment: I've added


                    willRespondWith: {
                        status: 200,
                        headers: {
                            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                            'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
                            'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'PUT, POST, GET, OPTIONS',
                        },
                        body: EXPECTED_BODY,
                    },


didn't help :(

Comment: btw, I've just added autoresponder to fiddler

localhost:1234/api returns and object

this response I'm able to see on Network tab... So, I'm not actually sure if this issue relates to cors. 
Also I've added cors: true in karma.conf.js

Comment: Added flag for disabling web security

https://i.imgur.com/gadZ8xx.jpg